# When pinging, the ping responses come from random domain names, but the same IP address?

Tags: dns, internet-connection, ping, connection

When I ping a site, I get ping responses from random domains.  You can see this in the paste below.  I started a ping, and surfed around a few sites, and the domain keeps changing.

I've also observed my internet is slow when approaching a new site, but after I reach the page, it loads quickly and I can usually navigate the site without slowdown.  I can stream HD movies with my connection (which is a DSL connection), so the speed is there, but there's something weird with the DNS I expect?

Also of interest, all the pings report around 95 ms, but the ping's are actually quite sporadic.  Meaning I'll sit for 10 seconds, then 3 or 4 pings will return very quickly, then there will be another long pause.  Despite some pings very clearly (by visual estimation) taking longer than others, they all report the same ping time.

This is my first super user post.  I hope this isn't too specific, but maybe it can help someone else.  Otherwise I'll try a technical support forum rather than the stack exchange FAQ sites.  (However, I did find a similar question on a similar FAQ site, but I couldn't see the answer because I wouldn't pay up.  So hopefully super users will serve me better.)

MORE INFO:

- I'm using Debian 6.
- I'm hard wired to my DSL router.
- A Windows laptop, connected wirelessly to the router, doesn't have
  the same problems, but Windows probably does pings differently. In
  particular I've noticed Windows doesn't report the domain in it's
  ping results.
- The ping results show below are from the computer with the
  "connection problems."

/etc/resolv.conf is below:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain domain.actdsltmp
search domain.actdsltmp
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 205.171.3.25
```

Ping command and results from terminal are below:

```
buttons@debiandesktop:~$ ping stackexchange.com
PING stackexchange.com (64.34.119.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=1 ttl=55 time=97.1 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=2 ttl=55 time=96.1 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=3 ttl=55 time=93.4 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=4 ttl=55 time=94.2 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=5 ttl=55 time=94.8 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=6 ttl=55 time=93.9 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=7 ttl=55 time=95.0 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=8 ttl=55 time=102 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=9 ttl=55 time=106 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=10 ttl=55 time=99.5 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=11 ttl=55 time=94.2 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=12 ttl=55 time=94.0 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=13 ttl=55 time=93.8 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=14 ttl=55 time=94.2 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=15 ttl=55 time=94.2 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=16 ttl=55 time=96.9 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=17 ttl=55 time=94.0 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=18 ttl=55 time=98.0 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=19 ttl=55 time=120 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=20 ttl=55 time=93.7 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=21 ttl=55 time=103 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=22 ttl=55 time=94.4 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=23 ttl=55 time=97.2 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=24 ttl=55 time=102 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=25 ttl=55 time=93.8 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=26 ttl=55 time=93.7 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=27 ttl=55 time=94.5 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=28 ttl=55 time=94.3 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=29 ttl=55 time=96.2 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=30 ttl=55 time=94.1 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=31 ttl=55 time=95.5 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=32 ttl=55 time=95.2 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=33 ttl=55 time=95.5 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=34 ttl=55 time=94.2 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=35 ttl=55 time=94.3 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=36 ttl=55 time=95.8 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=37 ttl=55 time=94.5 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=38 ttl=55 time=93.6 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=39 ttl=55 time=93.4 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=40 ttl=55 time=93.6 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=41 ttl=55 time=96.4 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=42 ttl=55 time=108 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=43 ttl=55 time=95.5 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=44 ttl=55 time=93.8 ms
64 bytes from s0.2mdn.net (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=45 ttl=55 time=95.0 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=46 ttl=55 time=93.7 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=47 ttl=55 time=99.0 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=48 ttl=55 time=94.0 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=49 ttl=55 time=93.8 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=50 ttl=55 time=97.0 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=51 ttl=55 time=94.3 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=52 ttl=55 time=96.2 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=53 ttl=55 time=101 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=54 ttl=55 time=94.8 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=55 ttl=55 time=95.1 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=56 ttl=55 time=95.7 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=57 ttl=55 time=94.2 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=58 ttl=55 time=99.2 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=59 ttl=55 time=109 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=60 ttl=55 time=94.0 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=61 ttl=55 time=98.0 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=62 ttl=55 time=158 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=63 ttl=55 time=99.0 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=64 ttl=55 time=94.6 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=65 ttl=55 time=94.4 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=66 ttl=55 time=93.7 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=67 ttl=55 time=99.9 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=68 ttl=55 time=96.2 ms
64 bytes from a1.twimg.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=69 ttl=55 time=93.3 ms
64 bytes from altfarm.mediaplex.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=70 ttl=55 time=94.9 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=71 ttl=55 time=94.2 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=72 ttl=55 time=93.9 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=73 ttl=55 time=93.9 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=74 ttl=55 time=95.1 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=75 ttl=55 time=93.7 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=76 ttl=55 time=94.2 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=77 ttl=55 time=94.8 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=78 ttl=55 time=96.2 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=79 ttl=55 time=94.0 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=80 ttl=55 time=96.1 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=81 ttl=55 time=94.8 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=82 ttl=55 time=94.0 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=83 ttl=55 time=96.5 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=84 ttl=55 time=96.0 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=85 ttl=55 time=93.8 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=86 ttl=55 time=97.8 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=87 ttl=55 time=98.4 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=88 ttl=55 time=128 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=89 ttl=55 time=96.3 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=90 ttl=55 time=94.1 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=91 ttl=55 time=94.6 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=92 ttl=55 time=97.6 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=93 ttl=55 time=94.3 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=94 ttl=55 time=94.1 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=95 ttl=55 time=94.5 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=96 ttl=55 time=93.7 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=97 ttl=55 time=93.9 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=98 ttl=55 time=94.2 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=99 ttl=55 time=94.0 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=100 ttl=55 time=93.8 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=101 ttl=55 time=95.7 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=102 ttl=55 time=93.9 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=103 ttl=55 time=94.1 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=104 ttl=55 time=97.6 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=105 ttl=55 time=115 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=106 ttl=55 time=94.8 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=107 ttl=55 time=104 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=108 ttl=55 time=94.3 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=109 ttl=55 time=93.8 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=110 ttl=55 time=96.0 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=111 ttl=55 time=94.3 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=112 ttl=55 time=101 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=113 ttl=55 time=95.1 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=114 ttl=55 time=94.4 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=115 ttl=55 time=94.6 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=116 ttl=55 time=94.8 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=117 ttl=55 time=97.5 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=118 ttl=55 time=96.0 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=119 ttl=55 time=96.9 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=120 ttl=55 time=97.9 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=121 ttl=55 time=93.7 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=122 ttl=55 time=95.1 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=123 ttl=55 time=95.0 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=124 ttl=55 time=99.6 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=125 ttl=55 time=95.4 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=126 ttl=55 time=93.8 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=127 ttl=55 time=93.7 ms
64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=128 ttl=55 time=94.2 ms
^C64 bytes from ssl.gstatic.com (64.34.119.12): icmp_req=129 ttl=55 time=94.1 ms
```

Comment: Are you pinging from the same machine you are using? Or are you logging into a remote machine and pinging from it?

Comment: What does your /etc/resolv.conf look like?

Comment: Your first name server is a private, internal name server. That could be the problem. FYI I don't see the problem you are seeing here.

Comment: The 192.168.0.1 nameserver might be the address of your router; it's a pretty common default. If that's the case, you should have a look at the router configuration to see if it's doing anything with DNS requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how ping works:

```
ping stackexchange.com
```

1. It fires a DNS query to resolve `stackexchange.com`
2. It then sends ICMP (ping) requests to the IP address obtained from the DNS query
3. On successful reply, it then queries DNS for the domain of the source of the ICMP reply

This must mean your DNS responds differently to the subsequent reverse lookup queries.

> To try this out yourself, run **nslookup 64.34.119.12** at the command prompt at different times to see what u get as a result.

[image: ping stackexchange.com]

Comment: Are you saying there's nothing unusual about what I'm seeing? Why do ping responses come from totally unrelated domains? Are you saying all those random domains really have the same IP address? Because that's sure what the ping results make it look like.

Comment: Your ping responses are coming from the same `ip address`. Your DNS server is `reverse resolving` it to `different domains`. It's possible for `several domains` to share the same `ip address`. For example, on my system, *www.gogle.com* and *www.gooogle.com* resolve to the same set of addresses. That said, I don't want to rule out unexpected behavior from your DNS server.

Comment: +1 for the good information, although I don't think this is a specific solution to my problem.  I'm starting to think it's related to IPv6.